# Redirect /api/ requests to /api/index.php with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to create a `.htaccess` file that will:

- match URLs starting with `/api/` and load `/api/index.php`

  - Examples: `/api/user`, `/api/product`, `/api/product/1`...
- open files in root directory if they exist

  - Examples: `/style.css`, `/script.js`...
- otherwise redirect other requests to `/index.html`

  - Examples: `/`, `/login`, `/user`, `/product`, `/product/1`...

I got the part where files from root directory shows up normally and routes without `/api` load the `index.html`, but I can't figure out the api path.

This is my `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /api
    #RewriteRule ^/api/ index.php [QSA,L]

    #RewriteRule ^/api$ /api/index.php [QSA,L]

    #RewriteRule ^api api/index.php [QSA,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Commented lines are failed attempts

Comment: Why not simply put all indexes to `.php` file? Also `/api/` will automatically search for `index.*` file

Comment: @Martin That's not really what I want to achieve

Comment: @Justinas I'm not really sure what you mean by putting all indexes to `.php` file, but by using the .htacess file I provided I get 404 error

Comment: @Matej no, but the answer perfectly shows you how to understand `Mod_rewrite` and how tocomplete your answer yourself. Cheers

Comment: Well, I'm trying to make it work with the information provided by you @Martin, but I can't get it to work. I am trying this at the moment `RewriteRule ^api/([^/.]+)/?$ api/index.php [QSA,L]`, but without any luck.

Comment: your question seems incomplete, or do you really want that all calls to `/api/etc` gets redirected to `/api/index.php` **without knowing** if it was `/user` `/product` or something else? If `/api/index.php` is meant to answer different type of calls, you should have a capturing group and a parameter just like in the duplicate (which answers your question well IMO)

Comment: @Kaddath Yes, I want them all to redirect to the index.php. I got a Slim router in there

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44618575/htaccess-slim-and-angular2) answer helped me.